# how to enable open gl es for android avds

Tags: android, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0, android-virtual-device

I am unable to get my AVD's to support HW rendering accoriding to my marmalade app, it defaults to its software renderer.

How do you check if your AVD supports HW rendering and how do you turn it on?

Also could it be my newish gpu? does your machine have to meet certain requirements before open gl es 1.1+ can be simulated?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when I drew off the end of my surface it corrupted memory and was causing the illusion of my app not working on a GPU enabled AVD.